# How to convert nested JSON in RequestBody to an entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson

Following is the body of `POST` request to my endpoint:

```json
{
    "availabilityMap":
    {
        "2021-07-18":["9AM-10AM", "OT"],
        "2021-07-19":["9AM-10AM", "OPD"],
        .
        .
    }
    
}
```

and following is the skeleton of my controller:

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/appointment", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        produces= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity newAppointment(@RequestBody /* WHAT TO PUT HERE?*/) {

}
```

How do I define an entity so that the `@RequestBody` is automatically converted to an entity? Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class RequestVO {

    public Map<String, List<String>> availabilityMap;

    public Map<String, List<String>> getAvailabilityMap() {
        return availabilityMap;
    }

    public void setAvailabilityMap(Map<String, List<String>> availabilityMap) {
        this.availabilityMap = availabilityMap;
    }
}
```

`{}` can be represented as an object or a map, and `[]` can be represented as an implementation class of a Collection. (Commonly used are List and Set, which are also interfaces. The specific classes are specified by the sequence number framework. You can also use implementation classes such as HashMap.) For `{}`, using an object or a map depends on whether the field is fixed or not. In the example, `availabilityMap` is a fixed-name field, so the object is used. `2021-07-18` is an indefinite date or other class, so use Map. For one object, if its field is another object, you may need to write a new java class.

Comment: Should it be one more level deep? To accommodate the top level field "availabilityMap" ?

Comment: I updated the answer to explain why it was designed this way.

Answer (score 2):

In general, we prepare dto or resource for request and response. If your requests or responses are related to the database, it should be dto, otherwise you should mark it as a resource and you can perform automatic mapping operations using MapStruct.

```
@Data
public class RequestDto {

    public Map<String, List<String>> availabilityMap;

}
```

Comment: Yes I need to flatten the structure and then store it in a SQL table. In your answer I am not sure if the `RequestDto` would be able to accommodate the top level tag "availabilityMap"? Something like this I was thinking - `Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>`

Comment: Thank you I understood it now :) Unfortunately cant mark both the answers correct and not enough reputation to upvote :|